# Updated data for clicked row but scroll down the listview some row will also updated

Tags: java, android, sql-server, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to update data for clicked row with dialog box. I can updated but when i scroll down some row will also updated. Then, when i scroll up again the data will random updated to other row.

Below is my adapter code:

```
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView productid, productname, pcs, cs;
        ImageView dist;
    }

    public List<Product_List> parkingList;

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<Product_List> arrayList;

    private MyAppAdapter(List<Product_List> apps, Context context) {
        this.parkingList = apps;
        this.context = context;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Product_List>();
        arrayList.addAll(parkingList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return parkingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        final MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlist, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.productid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productid);
            viewHolder.productname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productname);
            viewHolder.pcs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pcs);
            viewHolder.cs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cs);
            viewHolder.dist = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.productid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getInvtID() + "");
        viewHolder.productname.setText(parkingList.get(position).getDescr() + "");

        final String a = viewHolder.productid.getText().toString();
        final String b = viewHolder.productname.getText().toString();

        if ( position % 2 == 0) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ECEAEA"));
        }

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setTitle("Inventory Checking");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.inventory);
                dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                final TextView productids = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.productids);
                productids.setText(a);
                final TextView productdesc = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.productdesc);
                productdesc.setText(b);
                final EditText pcss = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pcss);
                final EditText css = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.css);
                final RadioButton btnyes = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnyes);
                final RadioButton btnno = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnno);
                btnno.setChecked(true);
                Button btnsave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
                btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewHolder.pcs.setText(pcss.getText().toString());
                        viewHolder.cs.setText(css.getText().toString());

                        if (btnyes.isChecked()) {
                            viewHolder.dist.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.dist.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
                        }

                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This is my adapter code.

```
    String msg="Found";
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(InventoryChecking1.this, "Synchronising",
                "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (conn == null) {
                success = false;
            } else {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if (rs != null) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        try {
                            if (rs.getString("Status").equals("A") || rs.getString("Status").equals("AC")) {
                                itemsArrayList.add(new Product_List(rs.getString("InvtID"), rs.getString("Descr"), rs.getString("Brand"),
                                        rs.getString("Category")));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    msg = "Found";
                    success = true;
                } else {
                    msg = "No Data found!";
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            msg = writer.toString();
            success = false;
        }

        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        progress.dismiss();
        // Toast.makeText(SellerActivity.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (success == false) {
        } else {
            try {
                myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemsArrayList, InventoryChecking1.this);
                listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change data in list instead of UI Views just change in list and notify
the adapter:

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Product_List product_list = new Product_List(pcss.getText().toString(),css.getText().toString());
                    parkingList.set( position,product_list );

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });
```

Comment: hi sorry not really understand my problem is when i update listview with dialog box after updated when i scroll the value that i updated will random update to another row